# Ad- instead of co- as a prefix for morphism

Tags: prefix

I want to find a prefix for morphism to get the meaning "relevance of the form of an entity to given criteria"

Does it make sense to use ad- for this? Co- also makes sense but the word "comorphism" does not sound exactly right e.g. "correlation of forms given circumstances" and also has an established use in mathematics with the latter meaning.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is being a prefix a requisite, or some other form of compound word is good too?

Comment: Thank you! Some compound form could potentially work too. Got the idea from the way 'advantage' is formed, not married to it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trying out words which use the Greek root MORPH some don't fit, they would be wrong.

> KATA contrary
>   ANA upstream,  against the flow.

Some would fit your meaning but are already taken,

> META change adaptation against
>   PARA alongside

metamorphic and paramorphic are geological terms for historically changed rock.

> EPI with respect to

**Epimorphic** - literal meaning: with respect to the form; up against the form combines both the idea of 'adaptation,' and the central concept of 'form.'

Epimorph is the instance of adaptation; epimorphic describes such instances; epimorphism is the process.

Comment: I like the way epimorph- sounds but the prefix epi- is most commonly seen with "epigenetics" to mean "adjacent to, influencing genetics" which kind of mixes up things

Comment: Actually nvm that, epimorphism as in set theory is pretty close. Thanks much!